# Updated list is not showing in jsp page even after successful execution of delete query

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

My jsp page code is here:

```
<form id="target" >
        <table id="table">
            <tr id="firstrow"><th>Product Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price/unit</th><th>Vendor's Name</th><th>actions</th></tr>

                <c:forEach var="current" items="${sessionScope.productname}" >
                <tr id="select_one">
                    <input id="productId" type="hidden" name="productId" value="<c:out value="${current.productId}" />"/>
                    <td><input id="productName" class="box" type="" name="productName"  value="<c:out value="${current.productName}" />" readonly></td>
                    <td><input id="quantity"  class="box" type="" name="quantity"  value="<c:out value="${current.quantity}"/>" readonly></td>
                    <td><input id="price" class="box" type="" name="price"  value="<c:out value="${current.price}"/>" readonly></td>
                    <td><input id="vname" class="box" type="" name="vname" value="<c:out value="${current.vname}"/>" readonly></td>
                    <td>
                    <input class="Edit" type="button" name="action" value="Edit">
                    <input  class="delete"type="button" name="action" value="Delete">
                    </td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>

        </table>
    </form>
```

The jQuery which I have written for "Delete" button is(which is also working fine)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".delete").click(function() 
            {
             $("#table").remove();  
                var productId=$(this).closest('tr').find("#productId").val();

                 var param = {productId:productId};

                $.ajax({
                  url: './deleteproduct',
                   data: param, 
                   type: 'post',
                    success: function(result) {
                    location.reload();
                  }
                });
            });

});
```

And my deleteproduct() fuction code is

```
public static boolean deleteProduct(int productId)  {
    boolean status=false;
    String driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String dbUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pmsdb?&relaxAutoCommit=true";
    String dbUser="root";
    String dbPswd="root";


    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    Connection con=null;

    try{

        Class.forName(driverClass);
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,dbUser,dbPswd);

        pstmt=con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM `pms_prd_details` WHERE `producid`=?");
        pstmt.setInt(1, productId);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
        System.out.println("Record is deleted!");

    }catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally{
        if (con != null) {  
            try {  
                con.close();  
            } catch (SQLException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  
        if (pstmt != null) {  
            try {  
                pstmt.close();  
            } catch (SQLException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  

    }
    return status;
}
```

And here is also my servlet's doPost() method

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
    int productId=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("productId"));
    System.out.println(productId);
    DeleteProductFromList dpd=new DeleteProductFromList();
     if (dpd.deleteProduct(productId)){
            System.out.println("true");
            ShowProduclist lst= new ShowProduclist();
            request.getSession().setAttribute("productname", lst.showProductlist());
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("ProductList.jsp");    
            rd.include(request,response); 

     }
}
```

My eaxact question is that, when I call the

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("productname", lst.showProductlist());
```

for creating new record or updating new record and try to show in the same jsp page it's working fine. But at the time of deletion I did the same thing but although it has deleted the record from database successfully in my jsp page it is showing the already deleted record.What is going on?Please help me thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to understand how Ajax works. When you call your delete inside jQuery with ajax, there is no page reload. Your client still have the same HTML, but he just send delete request in background.

So whole communication is inside JavaScript. Your server can respond with some status (for example 200 OK) and you can make some action in JavaScript on this response from server in your success function (delete object from HTML) using JavaScript/jQuery something like this:

```
$("#item10").remove()
```

You can try use some tools like Firebug (plugin for Firefox) to track your HTML/Ajax requests to figure out what is happening.

### Update

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".delete").click(function() 
            {

                var productId=$(this).closest('tr').find("#productId").val();

                 var param = {productId:productId};

                $.ajax({
                  url: './deleteproduct',
                   data: param, 
                   type: 'post',
                    success: function(result) {
                    //find row to delete and use remove();
                  }
                });
            });

});
```

Comment: Thank you I can understand what was my mistake I have updated my code it's work fine. If you think this code is not good please let me know. Thank you again for your help

Comment: @Paramita It would be better to remove element from html using javascript/jquery as i said instead of reload. When you make reload, client send request to your server and server have to prepare whole page. But the only change in your whole page when you delete item is remove just one row from your table and you can indicate which row to delete

Comment: Ok .Now I got it.Thank you.